# CA2000 and I don't see the reason

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dispose

I'm currently writing a project and I use Microsoft Code Analysis and I do receive the following error:

CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope.

This is on code which I've written around the Entity Framework.

```
public bool IsInstalled(InstallationContext context)
{
    var dbContext = new ScheduleFrameworkDataContext();
    var repository = new TaskRepository(dbContext);

    try
    {
        // Check if there is already a task with the same name.
        if (repository.Get().Select(x => x.Name == context.InstallationParameters.Name).Any())
        { return true; }
    }
    finally { dbContext.Dispose(); }

    return false;
}
```

Now, I do think that my context is disposed because it's in the finally block. (The context is a EF Code First DB Context). 
However, I still receive that error.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Is the TaskRepository disposeable?

Comment: No, it isn't. But isn't the error on the context itself? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @KevinDeConinck do you get the error if you wrap your context with the `using` statement? That's effectively what the `using` does anyway and is the recommended way of disposing objects that implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Did you try the same code but using a "using" statement? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx
All I can think of is that the Code Analysis does not recognize the disposal from the finally clause.

Comment: By doing it with the 'Using' logic, the warning are surpressed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code analysis tool is right in this instance.

If the `TaskRepository()` constructor throws, the `finally` block won't run (since the exception is thrown outside of the `try` block), and `dbContext` will not be disposed.

Moving the constructor call and the assignment to `repository` inside the `try` block would suppress the warning.